# C# Monotouch/Xamarin.iOS - Pushing A Navigation Controller Is Not Supported

Tags: c#, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin, pushviewcontroller

**I have an app written for iOS7....**

**I Have The Following Code In My AppDelegate**

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
        public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
        {
            // class-level declarations
            UIWindow window;
            UINavigationController navigationController;
            HomeViewController_iPhone homeViewController;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            homeViewController = new HomeViewController_iPhone ();
            navigationController = new UINavigationController (homeViewController);
            window.RootViewController = navigationController;
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }
    }
```

**It fails on this line**

```
navigationController = new UINavigationController (homeViewController);
```

**HomeViewController is a UINavigationController class...**

**I Receive The Following Error When Building My Code**
MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown.
Objective-C exception thrown. Name NSInvalidArgumentException
Reason: Pushing A Navigation Controller Is Not Supported.

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself why do you create a new `UINavigationController` on your `UINavigationController` ?

If your `homeViewController` is a `UINavigationController` then simply do:

```
window.RootViewController = new HomeViewController_iPhone ();
```

or maybe your `homeViewController` should not be a navigation controller ?

Comment: That's a good point, but if I implement your suggestion, when I call this.NavigationController.PushViewController() from inside my homeViewController (which is a UINavigationController), then it tells me the navigationController of HomeViewController is NULL....

Comment: Do I have to explicit instantiate the navigationController of a view that is a UINavigationController ?

Comment: @Goober If your `homeViewController` _is_ a `UINavigationController` you would call `this.PushViewController()` to push something on your _own_ stack. Using `this.NavigationController.PushViewController()` you will try to push something on your `homeViewController`'s navigation controller. And since your controller is not _embedded into_ a `UINavigationController`but actually _is_ the same, you will get NULL.